# Maximum sum difference between two sorted array elements under one condition

Tags: sorting, arrays, greedy-algorithms

We're given two arrays $A$ and $B$ with size $N$ and $M$ respectively. We want to find a set $P = \{(a_1, b_1), \dots, (a_s,b_s)\}$ such that

- for each $i\in\{1, \dots, s\}$, $a_i\in A$, $b_i\in B$ and $a_i>b_i$ and $a_i,b_i$ musn't be chosen before;
- $\sum_{i=1}^s (a_i-b_i)$ is maximized.

A natural approach is to sort array $A$ in descending order and $B$ in ascending order, initialize $i$ and $j$ to $1$, then iterate: while $A[i] > B[j]$ add $A[i] - B[j]$. How we can prove that this solution works?

Comment: I've edited the question to, I hope, make it clearer, but a number of things are still unclear to me. Is $s$ a part of the input, or are we trying to choose $P$ as large as possible, so as to maximize the sum, and $s$ is the that $P$ end up being? Is $P$ really supposed to be a set, or is it a sequence? If the arrays are $A=[10,10,10,10]$, $B=[0,0,0,0]$, it seems that I want to add $(10,0)$ to $P$ four times, but that's not possible if $P$ is a set. How exactly does the iteration over $i$ and $j$ work in your proposed solution? Under what conditions are $i$ and $j$ incremented?

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as unclear, at the moment. I'll happily retract that or vote to reopen if the question is edited to make it clear.

Comment: It's still not much clearer. So you're saying that, in the example I gave, I _can't_ pick my pairs to be $(A[1],B[1]), ..., (A[4],B[4])$ because they all have the same value, $(10,0)$, even though I was using different "copies" of $10$ and $0$ each time? And you've still not said how the iteration on $i$ and $j$ works: we start with $i=j=1$ and if $A[i]>B[j]$, we add $(A[i],B[j])$ to $P$. But what if $A[i]\leq B[j]$? How do I change $i$ and $j$?

Comment: you just care about the chosen elements regardless their values and i meant by set of pairs P here just the set of pairs (first element from array A and the from B) maximizing the sum , but remember that if you choose one element from array A or array B you can't choose it anymore (it means if you choose one element from A with index i you can't choose A[i] anymore).

Comment: Now about the suggested algorithm you are going to itnitialize a pointer i to 1 (i.e the first cell) and iterating while(i <= N && i <= M && A[i] > B[i]) and just add the difference (A[i] - B[i]) to the total sum (sum is initialized to 0).

Comment: Please don't reply in the comments.  Instead, edit the question to ensure it is clear and to address all feedback you receive.  The question should read well and be clear for someone who encounters the question for the first time.  When you have edited the question, it can be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two sets A and B.  Using i and j only once maximize the ∑(a[i] - b[j]).  Not required to use and i and j.

I don't know if this is a hard proof but

For $A[i] > B[j]$
∑(a[i]−b[i])  =  ∑(a[i]) - ∑(b[i])

So the problem is reduced to maximize $A[i] > B[j]$
Reverse sorting maximizes the number of $A[i] > B[j]$

Or another way to say it
maximizes ∑(a[i]) and minimizes ∑(b[i])
Descending sorting maximizes ∑(a[i])
Ascending  sorting minimizes ∑(b[i])

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here or how it relates to the original problem.  If you understand the original problem statement, could you perhaps edit the question to make it clear what the problem statement is (clearing up the points raised in the comments)?

Comment: @D.W. It is accepted to it must relate.  Pretty simple maximize the sum of A[i] - B[j] with no reuse of i or j and not required to use all i or j.  OP changes notation so it is confusing.  I just kind of figured out what he was really asking.